# How to customize Parse push notification icon in Unity for Android games?

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I implemented push notification for my Android game using Parse Unity SDK. I tried to customise the notification icon with following steps:

1.Add the following metadata tag in Android manifest[(from this tutorial)](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon"/>
```

2.Add notification_icon.png in Assets/Plugins/Androids/res/drawable/

However it does not work, how should I customise the icon?